# Yii2 app update deployment to shared host

Tags: yii2, composer-php, package, continuous-deployment

My scenario is: I'm developing my first non-toy application with yii2. I'm doing it on a dev server I can access via ssh. Eventually I have to deploy the app to my customer's server which turns out to be a bare hosting with no ssh access.

The first deployment is ok, I download everything and upload everything on the other server, change the config files and so on.

Every version deployment from that day on has been painfull. Every time I install via composer some new plugin/widget/package I cannot make it work on the production server. There are always broken packages, fatal errors and so on. After a brave fight I ended up surrending, deleting everything from production server and uploading it from scratch, which is not very handy.

The question is: which are the steps to correctly deploy my updates copying only the needed files in order to make packages work at the first try? Is composer.json needed? composer.lock? Are the *vendor* folders enough? Do the *assets* folders need to be copied every time or I can assume they are fixed and I need to upload only the new ones?

Comment: No SSH access? I suggest to choose another hosting.

Comment: Neither my decision nor something I have power on, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hosting situation is very unfortunate. Hopefully you can persuade your client to switch to some hosting package that has shell access.

Instead of syncing, you can (and probably should) remove all files from `/backend/web/assets`, `/backend/web/runtime`, `/frontend/web/assets`, and `/frontend/web/runtime` when deploying. Those files are temporary anyway.

Composer's `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are not relevant, because you're not running composer on your hosting.

You should sync the `vendor` directory. Keep in mind that some files there do change (`autoload.php` and so on), so you can't just upload files that don't exist on the server already, you need to sync.

There's also a page in [yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html) on deploying to shared hosting.

P.S.: You can also try uploading `composer.phar` to your directory and running composer from php using `exec`. Also, try installing a php web shell.

Comment: Completely answers my question. Especially usefull the fact that `assets` is temporary, especially witful the idea of using composer via `exec`, I'll definitely give it a try

Comment: Either that, or just get some decent hosting :)